# Uncaught Error: JIT compiler unavailable in Angular 12

Tags: angular, typescript, jit

For a few days I have a problem with a certain error: Uncaught Error: JIT compiler unavailable.
After upgrading angular from version 8 to 12 there was a
problem that I run the ng build --prod --output-path = dist command and
build Angular I have no problems, but when I start the page, this problem with JIT pops up.
I have tried all the solutions from stack overflow like I add in my package.json

```js
scripts{
 "postinstall": "ngcc --properties es5 browser module main --first-only"
}
```

I add in main.ts '@angular/compiler'
Also in tsconfig.json in "angularCompilerOptions" I changed  "enableIvy" to true
One post says to change to true, the other that to false, but none of these solutions work for me.
I reinstall node_modules couple of times and adding couple of dependecies but nothing really worked.
This is my tsconfig file:

```js
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "es2020",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "skipLibCheck": true, 
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2015",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths": {
      // "tslib": ["../frontend/node_modules/tslib/tslib.d.ts"]
    }
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "enableIvy": true,
  }
}
```

In my package.json i add this line of code:

```js
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "ngcc --properties es2015 browser module main --first-only --create-ivy-entry-points"
}
```

In angular.json i changed aot: true, and buildOptimizer: false but it didin't change anything at all.
In this post "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68798086/jit-compiler-unavailable-after-angular-update" there is answer
about changing Webpack configuration. But we dont use webpack so i dont really understand this.
Can you help with this issue?

Comment: I'm facing similar issue. Any thing you got to know?

Comment: u found a solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked to call `ng build --aot=true` when building. Probably just a workaround, but I found no other solution.

Answer (score 0):

After one thousand tries... I found that turning "aot" false made the build work properly. Without "aot", we have to turn the "buildOptimizer" to false too. angular.json section "production" "aot": false, "buildOptimizer": false,

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler) Angular started using AOT compilation as default with Angular 9. It sounds like you want to continue using JIT, therefore you have to disable `aot` in the `angular.json`:

Building on [George Márcio Cardoso](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19316719/george-m%c3%a1rcio-cardoso)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72579909/16907308), I had to disable ahead-of-time compilation and enable buildOptimization for it to work. I am using NSwag to generate a TS client for my API which I then put into an npm package, thus requiring JIT compilation since it's not a full project.

My `angular.json` for the project using the npm package (package requires JIT, project was AOT) now looks like this:

```
{
  ...
  "projects": {
    "my-project-using-npm": {
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "aot": false,
            "buildOptimizer": false,
            ...
```

(snippet simplified for readability)