# What is ngDevMode property?

Tags: angular

From Angular [documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/enableProdMode),

> One important assertion this disables verifies that a change detection pass does not result in additional changes to any bindings (also known as unidirectional data flow).

But this does not seem to be referencing the same development mode concept.

From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68798086/jit-compiler-unavailable-after-angular-update), we can see in the validated answer that the ngDevMode is a configuration property used by the TerserPlugin.

I can't find any documentation on it and only issues with this property. What does it do, how or where do we set it and is it related only to the TerserPlugin?

Comment: You don't set `ngDevMode` directly, but calling `enableProdMode();` in main.ts will. Angular has many assertings and debugging information in their code, which will be removed for production (when `ngDevMode` is false).

Comment: Actually it seems like the production mode activated with the `enableProdMode()` method is not the same as the ngDevMode? When I don't activate the prod mode (by not making this call), I don't get the expected error output as mentioned in the question I referenced, but I do when I provide the constant ngDevMode to Webpack with the Webpack DefinePlugin