# JIT compiler unavailable in Angular 14

Tags: angular, compiler-warnings, jit, angular14

I have upgraded my angular version from 7 to 14. I have resolved all the errors and compiled successfully on **ng serve**. but we I try to run app using **localhost:4200** I am getting error in browser console that

```js
main.js:1 Uncaught Error: JIT compiler unavailable
    at ls (main.js:1:1922908)
    at Module.w3 (main.js:1:2080648)
    at main.js:1:4540
    at 44226 (main.js:1:4801)
    at r (runtime.js:1:147)
    at 73638 (main.js:1:352642)
    at r (runtime.js:1:147)
    at Ee (main.js:1:2720908)
    at main.js:1:2720929
    at f (runtime.js:1:4115)
```

Which is most probably due deprecated libraries, I have been asked to resolve this error without replacing some libraries. I am blank in this matter... the project I am working on is way old.

here is my Packages.json file:

```js
{
  "name": "wsi-portal",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "install": "npm run napa",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "modernizr": "modernizr -c modernizr-config.json -d src/modernizr.js",
    "postinstall": "ngcc --properties es2015 browser module main --first-only --create-ivy-entry-points",
    "napa": "napa",
    "ng-high-memory": "node --max_old_space_size=16384 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng"
  },
  "browser": {
    "child_process": false
  },
  "private": true,
  "napa": {
    "jquery.flot.spline": "miloszfalinski/jquery.flot.spline",
    "ika.jvectormap": "kakirigi/ika.jvectormap",
    "flot": "flot/flot#v0.8.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-webpack": "^0.1401.0",
    "@angular/animations": "~14.0.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "^14.0.4",
    "@angular/common": "~14.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "~14.0.5",
    "@angular/core": "~14.0.5",
    "@angular/forms": "~14.0.5",
    "@angular/material": "^14.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~14.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~14.0.5",
    "@angular/router": "^14.0.5",
    "@circlon/angular-tree-component": "^11.0.4",
    "@fullcalendar/angular": "^5.11.0",
    "@fullcalendar/bootstrap": "^5.11.0",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^5.11.0",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.11.0",
    "@fullcalendar/google-calendar": "^5.11.0",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^5.11.0",
    "@fullcalendar/list": "^5.11.0",
    "@fullcalendar/luxon": "^5.11.0",
    "@fullcalendar/moment": "^5.11.0",
    "@fullcalendar/moment-timezone": "^5.11.0",
    "@fullcalendar/rrule": "^5.11.0",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^5.11.0",
    "@kolkov/angular-editor": "^2.1.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^14.1.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "@pascalhonegger/ng-datatable": "^14.0.0",
    "@types/angular": "^1.8.4",
    "angular-date-value-accessor": "^2.0.1",
    "angular-google-recaptcha": "^1.0.3",
    "angular-mgl-timeline": "^0.4.0",
    "angular2-toaster": "^11.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.1",
    "codemirror": "^5.65.7",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "easy-pie-chart": "^2.1.7",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "format-currency": "^1.0.0",
    "fullcalendar": "^5.11.0",
    "html2canvas": "1.0.0-rc.1",
    "https-proxy-agent": "^5.0.1",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "jquery-slimscroll": "^1.3.8",
    "jquery-sparkline": "^2.4.0",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
    "jquery.browser": "^0.1.0",
    "jquery.flot.tooltip": "github:krzysu/flot.tooltip",
    "jspdf-autotable": "^3.1.1",
    "libphonenumber-js": "^1.10.10",
    "loaders.css": "0.1.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "mime": "^2.4.4",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.6.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ng-click-outside2": "^11.1.0",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.2.3",
    "ng-pick-datetime": "^7.0.0",
    "ng-select": "^1.0.2",
    "ng2-alt-summernote": "^2.0.0",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.4.2",
    "ng2-ckeditor": "^1.3.3",
    "ng2-daterangepicker": "^3.0.1",
    "ng2-dnd": "^4.2.0",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.4.0",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^9.0.0",
    "ng2-pdfjs-viewer": "^13.2.2",
    "ng2-progress-bar": "0.0.8",
    "ng2-select": "^2.0.0",
    "ng2-validation": "^4.1.0",
    "ng4-click-outside": "^1.0.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^8.0.0",
    "ngx-chips": "^1.9.8",
    "ngx-mask": "^14.0.3",
    "ngx-materialize": "^0.0.1",
    "ngx-modialog": "^5.0.1",
    "ngx-progress-bar": "^0.0.10",
    "node-sass": "^7.0.1",
    "npm-check-updates": "^14.1.1",
    "pdfmake": "^0.2.5",
    "popper": "^1.0.1",
    "popsicle-proxy-agent": "^3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "7.5.5",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
    "rxjs-observable": "^0.0.7",
    "screenfull": "^3.3.3",
    "simple-line-icons": "^2.4.1",
    "summernote": "^0.8.11",
    "sweetalert": "^1.1.3",
    "tslib": "^2.4.0",
    "typings": "^2.1.1",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.0.5",
    "@angular/cli": "^14.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~14.0.5",
    "@angular/language-service": "~14.0.5",
    "@angular/localize": "^14.0.5",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.30.20",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/jest": "^28.1.4",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.14",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.108",
    "@types/mocha": "^9.1.1",
    "@types/node": "^8.10.48",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "core-js": "^3.23.3",
    "husky": "^8.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "jspdf": "^1.5.3",
    "karma": "^6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "napa": "^3.0.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~4.7.4"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```js
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    //"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2020",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2019",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "types": [ "googlemaps" ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "compilationMode": "partial",
    "disableTypeScriptVersionCheck": true,
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "enableIvy": true,
    "enableLegacyTemplate": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictMetadataEmit": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
```

angular.json

```js
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "wsi-portal": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          //"builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
              "lodash",
              "babel-runtime/helpers"
            ],
            //"customWebpackConfig": {
            //  "path": "./extra-webpack.config.js"
            //},
            "outputPath": "dist/wsi-portal",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",

            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "src/app/shared/styles/themes/theme-f.scss",
              "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
              "node_modules/loaders.css/loaders.css",
              "node_modules/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css",
              "node_modules/summernote/dist/summernote.css",
              "node_modules/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.css",
              "node_modules/simple-line-icons/css/simple-line-icons.css",
              "node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css",
              "node_modules/@fullcalendar/common/main.css",
              "node_modules/@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css",
              "node_modules/@fullcalendar/timegrid/main.css",
              "node_modules/@fullcalendar/list/main.css"

            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
              "node_modules/flot/jquery.flot.js",
              "node_modules/jquery.flot.tooltip/js/jquery.flot.tooltip.js",
              "node_modules/flot/jquery.flot.resize.js",
              "node_modules/flot/jquery.flot.pie.js",
              "node_modules/flot/jquery.flot.time.js",
              "node_modules/flot/jquery.flot.categories.js",
              "node_modules/jquery.flot.spline/jquery.flot.spline.js",
              "node_modules/jquery-sparkline/jquery.sparkline.js",
              "node_modules/easy-pie-chart/dist/easypiechart.js",
              "node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/js/modal.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/js/dropdown.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/js/tooltip.js",
              "node_modules/summernote/dist/summernote.js",
              "node_modules/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js",
              "node_modules/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.js"
            ]
            //,"es5BrowserSupport": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "30mb",
                  "maximumError": "30mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          //"builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server",
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "wsi-portal:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "wsi-portal:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          //"builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:extract-i18n",
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "wsi-portal:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:karma",
          //"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          //"builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:tslint",
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "wsi-portal-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          //"builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:protractor",
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "wsi-portal:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "wsi-portal:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          //"builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:tslint",
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "wsi-portal"
}
```

Comment: if you do `ng serve --prod` do you also get this error?

Comment: If possible can you create stackbliz or share example repo?

Comment: Can [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68798086/jit-compiler-unavailable-after-angular-update) help you? I haven't checked if it's a duplicate, but it seems to be related to your issue.

Comment: `I have been asked to resolve this error without replacing some libraries.` This isn't how updating works, you need to first check if all libraries used are even compatible to Angular 14 before you update. You will have to update and sometimes also replace libraries.

Comment: @FranciscoSantorelli I did `ng serve --configuration="production"` it didn't work. Errror status remained same.

Comment: @MikeS. I replaced libraries which were causing error, now there are just few warnings left.

Comment: What libraries @SanaT. ? Please complete the answer :(

Answer (score -1):

For me, I forgot to import the **CommonModule** into my shared module file. First time creating a shared module so rookie mistake on my part.

**shared-directives.module.ts**

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common'; //this needed to be imported
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MyDirective } from './my-directive';

@NgModule({
    imports:[CommonModule], //added CommonModule to imports
    declarations: [
        MyDirective 
    ],

    exports: [
        CommonModule,
        MyDirective
    ]
})
export class SharedDirectivesModule{}
```

I am not sure if you have to add the **CommonModule** to exports as I have seen samples with and without.
Anyway I found this solution after reviewing this [guide](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/using-shared-modules-in-angular) on shared modules