# How to include JIT compiler in angular 13 app manually

Tags: angular, include, jit

I am upgrading my angular app from 6 to 13. I was able to solve the dependencies and do ng build successfully.
When I ran the appplication, I am getting the below error.

```
main.js:1 Uncaught Error: JIT compiler unavailable
    at g (main.js:1:45697)
    at bt (main.js:1:198212)
    at main.js:1:561691
    at 5130 (main.js:1:561899)
    at t (runtime.js:1:143)
    at main.js:1:2275919
    at n (runtime.js:1:1550)
    at main.js:1:65
```

I tried to use aot = true in angular.json file and also modify "postinstall": "ngcc --properties es5 browser module main --first-only" in package.json.
I am still not able to resolve this issue.
Are there any options to include JIT compiler in the angular appplication, so it runs without errors.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68798086/jit-compiler-unavailable-after-angular-update

Comment: None of the solutions in above link is helping, not sure whats wrong...

Comment: @user1015388 Did you find solution for this ? I am also stuck after angular update 12

Comment: @Andrej12345,there were library dependency issues which caused this for me.

Comment: So after all dependencies were compatible with your angular version then the error was gone ?

Comment: DId you also debuged the problem to see more specific error ? When  debug I am getting that the problem is some depenency which comilationMode is set to partial. Did you had such dependencies ? I am using btw angular version 12

Comment: This dependency for example https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select/blob/master/src/ng-select/tsconfig.lib.json