After Updating from angular 15 to 16 Facing the error JIT compiler unavailable
I have updated from angular 15 to 16. I have updated all the core packages and angular material, the project is compiled successfully. But in the browser the screen goes blank and this error is displayed in the console:
`1. Error: JIT compiler unavailable
1. at lo (main.js:23:193457)
1. at m.get (main.js:23:318873)
1. at Je (main.js:23:167049)
1. at ud (main.js:23:215074)
1. at main.js:23:215445
1. at main.js:23:193665
1. at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
1. at Vs (main.js:23:193629)
1. at ud (main.js:23:215427)
1. at main.js:23:215445`

The project UI should be displayed in the browser and all functionality should work with minor issues. on angular 16. Blow is my package.json file
{
  "name": "ng-datta-able",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.1.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^16.2.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^16.2.14",
    "@angular/common": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/core": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/localize": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/material": "^16.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/router": "^16.2.12",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^5.0.2",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.5.1",
    "@fullcalendar/angular": "^5.10.2",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^5.10.1",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.10.1",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^5.10.1",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^5.10.1",
    "@iplab/ngx-file-upload": "^2.0.6",
    "@ks89/angular-modal-gallery": "^7.2.5",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^6.1.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^15.2.9",
    "@nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to": "^9.0.0",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-calendars": "^19.1.56",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-schedule": "^18.1.43",
    "ajv": "^8.0.0",
    "amazing-time-picker": "^1.8.0",
    "angular-archwizard": "^6.1.0",
    "angular-datatables": "^9.0.2",
    "angular-dual-listbox": "^5.0.1",
    "angular-highcharts-chart": "^1.0.2",
    "angular-morris-js": "^1.1.0",
    "angular-pell": "^0.1.0",
    "angular2-chartjs": "^0.5.1",
    "angular2-text-mask": "^9.0.0",
    "angular2-tinymce": "^3.3.0",
    "animate.css": "4.1.1",
    "apexcharts": "3.35.2",
    "bootstrap": "5.3.2",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.11.3",
    "d3": "^5.16.0",
    "datatables.net": "^1.11.5",
    "datatables.net-buttons": "^2.2.3",
    "datatables.net-buttons-dt": "^1.6.2",
    "datatables.net-colreorder": "^1.5.2",
    "datatables.net-colreorder-dt": "^1.5.2",
    "datatables.net-dt": "^1.13.3",
    "datatables.net-responsive": "^2.2.5",
    "datatables.net-responsive-dt": "^2.2.5",
    "datatables.net-select": "^1.3.4",
    "datatables.net-select-dt": "^1.3.1",
    "echarts": "^4.8.0",
    "famfamfam-flags": "^1.0.0",
    "fullcalendar": "^5.10.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "highcharts": "^8.1.2",
    "jszip": "^3.9.1",
    "line-awesome": "1.3.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "morris.js": "^0.5.0",
    "mousetrap": "^1.6.5",
    "ng-apexcharts": "1.6.0",
    "ng-click-outside": "^6.0.0",
    "ng-fullcalendar": "^2.0.3",
    "ng-number-formatter": "^1.5.0",
    "ng-select": "^1.0.2",
    "ng2-dragula": "^2.1.1",
    "ng2-google-charts": "^6.0.1",
    "ngx-bar-rating": "^1.1.0",
    "ngx-chips": "^2.1.0",
    "ngx-color-picker": "^17.0.0",
    "ngx-custom-validators": "^9.1.0",
    "ngx-echarts": "^5.0.0",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^8.0.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "^13.1.0",
    "nvd3": "^1.8.6",
    "peity": "^3.3.0",
    "prism-themes": "1.9.0",
    "raphael": "^2.3.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.3",
    "screenfull": "^5.0.2",
    "socicon": "3.0.5",
    "tinymce": "^4.8.3",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5",
    "zone.js": "^0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.2.14",
    "@angular/cli": "^16.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/language-service": "^16.2.12",
    "@types/datatables.net": "^1.10.18",
    "@types/datatables.net-buttons": "^1.4.3",
    "@types/datatables.net-select": "^1.2.6",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.36",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.0",
    "@types/mousetrap": "^1.6.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/sass-loader": "^8.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^13.3.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.3"
  }
}

tsconfig.json file
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "useDefineForClassFields":false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2022",
    "module": "es2020",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}

app.module.ts file
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { SharedModule } from './theme/shared/shared.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AdminComponent } from './theme/layout/admin/admin.component';
import { AuthComponent } from './theme/layout/auth/auth.component';
import { NavigationComponent } from './theme/layout/admin/navigation/navigation.component';
import { NavLogoComponent } from './theme/layout/admin/navigation/nav-logo/nav-logo.component';
import { NavContentComponent } from './theme/layout/admin/navigation/nav-content/nav-content.component';
import { NavigationItem } from './theme/layout/admin/navigation/navigation';
import { NavGroupComponent } from './theme/layout/admin/navigation/nav-content/nav-group/nav-group.component';
import { NavCollapseComponent } from './theme/layout/admin/navigation/nav-content/nav-collapse/nav-collapse.component';
import { NavItemComponent } from './theme/layout/admin/navigation/nav-content/nav-item/nav-item.component';
import { NavBarComponent } from './theme/layout/admin/nav-bar/nav-bar.component';
// import {ToggleFullScreenDirective} from './theme/shared/full-screen/toggle-full-screen';
import { NgbButtonsModule, NgbDropdownModule, NgbTabsetModule, NgbTooltipModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { NavLeftComponent } from './theme/layout/admin/nav-bar/nav-left/nav-left.component';
import { NavSearchComponent } from './theme/layout/admin/nav-bar/nav-left/nav-search/nav-search.component';
import { NavRightComponent } from './theme/layout/admin/nav-bar/nav-right/nav-right.component';
// import {ChatUserListComponent} from './theme/layout/admin/nav-bar/nav-right/chat-user-list/chat-user-list.component';
// import { FriendComponent } from './theme/layout/admin/nav-bar/nav-right/chat-user-list/friend/friend.component';
// import {ChatMsgComponent} from './theme/layout/admin/nav-bar/nav-right/chat-msg/chat-msg.component';
import { ConfigurationComponent } from './theme/layout/admin/configuration/configuration.component';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ToastrModule } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { DatePipe, HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
import { ErrorInterceptor, JwtInterceptor } from './_helpers';
import { BasePageComponent } from './theme/shared/components/base-page';

// import { LoaderComponent } from './theme/shared/loader/loader.component';
import { MatProgressSpinnerModule } from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import { AttachmentComponent } from './demo/pages/attachment/attachment.component';
import { MatIcon, MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { DocattachmentComponent } from './_components/shared/docattachment/docattachment.component';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
// import { NgxMaterialTimepickerModule } from 'ngx-material-timepicker';

import { MaterialModule } from './_shared/material.module';
// import { NavControlComponent } from './theme/layout/admin/nav-control/nav-control.component';
// import { DayService, WeekService, WorkWeekService, MonthService, AgendaService, MonthAgendaService, TimelineViewsService, TimelineMonthService } from '@syncfusion/ej2-angular-schedule';





@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AdminComponent,
    AuthComponent,
    NavigationComponent,
    NavLogoComponent,
    NavContentComponent,
    NavGroupComponent,
    NavCollapseComponent,
    NavItemComponent,
    NavBarComponent,
    // ToggleFullScreenDirective,
    NavLeftComponent,
    NavSearchComponent,
    NavRightComponent,
    // ChatUserListComponent,
    // FriendComponent,
    // ChatMsgComponent,
    ConfigurationComponent,
    BasePageComponent,
    AttachmentComponent,
    DocattachmentComponent,
    // NavControlComponent,




    // MatProgressSpinnerModule,




  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    // MatSelectModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    SharedModule,
    NgbDropdownModule,
    NgbTooltipModule,
    NgbButtonsModule,
    NgbTabsetModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ToastrModule.forRoot({
      preventDuplicates: true,
    }),
    FormsModule,

    NgbTabsetModule,

    NgbTooltipModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule, 
    // NgxMaterialTimepickerModule,
    MaterialModule,
    NgbModule,
  ],
  // providers: [NavigationItem],
  // schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],

  providers: [NavigationItem,
    DatePipe,
    { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy },
    //  { provide: NZ_I18N, useValue: en_US },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: JwtInterceptor, multi: true },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ErrorInterceptor, multi: true }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68798086/jit-compiler-unavailable-after-angular-update
